# Update Kendo NumericTextBox with MVVM on spin

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

Take a look at the MVVM example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/numerictextbox/mvvm.html):

**How can I get the MVVM value to update on the spin event (clicking the up or down arrows)**

Here is what I tried:

In the spin event, I tried to do

```
$("#ntb").getKendoNumericTextBox().trigger("change");
```

That worked but had weird side effects.

If there are enough elements on the DOM, the spin event will keep firing.

Another way to reproduce this is to take the code from [here (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/duqiyosa/3)

Insert it in a HTML file, load it in Chrome or FF and then insert a break point at this line:

```
$("#ntb").getKendoNumericTextBox().trigger("change");
```

Keep hitting continue and you will see the breakpoint get hit time after time.

In firefox, if my DOM is large enough, I get a repro without a breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your [`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/duqiyosa/1/) and I saw some errors in html and javascript. I think while you were testing different codes you forgot to correct it. Anyway I clean up and correct your codes and put them to this [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/SZPLk/1/).

After putting breakpoint (`debugger;`) I saw you are right `onSpin` event triggers infinitely but this odd act happens if you put a breakpoint in the event. If you remove breakpoint and put a `console.log("`onSpin`event triggered.");` you see everything is okay and the event just triggered just once.

I faced before with such issues in different scenarios for example using `alert()` instead of `console.log()` for debugging purpose.

---

Codes:

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    selectedNumber: 0,
    isEnabled: true,
    isVisible: true,
    onSpin: function () {
        //debugger;
        console.log("`onSpin` event triggered.");
        $("#ntb").getKendoNumericTextBox().trigger("change");
    },
    onChange: function () {}
});
kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup and confirming my repro, nice to know I'm not crazy. The problem is in Firefox, it repros without a breakpoint.. Chrome and IE are just fine.

Comment: @Matt I just test in IE10 and FF29 none of them repro the issue without breakpoint! Open ff console and go to the jsfiddle click on spins just triggers `onSpin` once for each click.

Comment: Sorry, it repros in FF if the DOM is large, I should have specified

Comment: @Matt: What about replacing `$("#ntb").getKendoNumericTextBox().trigger("change");` with `viewModel.set("selectedNumber", e.sender._value);` ? give it a try.

Comment: Still fires indefinitely when a breakpoint is set. I guess I'll wait for Telerik to get back to us and I'll post the solution here.

Comment: It is not a bug ! When there is a breakpoint, the focus will get to the debug window and that messes up the component behavior. It thinks you never stopped clicking so it increments indefinitely... until you click somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo support says to run this in the spin event:

```
this.set('selectedNumber', e.sender.element.val());
```

And that makes the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. It works for me.

ViewModel

```
viewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
        console.log("property Changed on spin ");
    });
```

Razor code

```
<input id="tbSlideDuration" data-role="numerictextbox"
                             data-format="#"
                             data-min="1"
                             data-max="100"
                             data-bind="value:slideDuration, events: {spin:change}" />
```

this will call the change event under the hood :)